# Interstitial iAd fails in landscape/horizontal (Spritekit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad, landscape

Hello Stackoverflow users, Im back again with another problem with my interstitial ads. This is the code I am using to display ads:

```
-(void) loadInterstitialAd {
     NSLog(@"loadInterstitialAd");
     _interstitialAd = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
     _interstitialAd.delegate = self;
     adShowing = true;
}
-(void) interstitialAdWillLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
}
-(void) interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidLoad");
    interstitialAdView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    interstitialAdView.frame = (self.view.bounds);
    [self.view addSubview:interstitialAdView];

    [_interstitialAd presentInView:interstitialAdView];
    [UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];
}
-(void) interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdActionDidFinish");
    [interstitialAdView removeFromSuperview];
    adShowing = false;
}
-(void) interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // you must take this funcion , because without it ADInterstitial iAd will not work
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    adShowing = false;
}
-(void) interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd{
    // you must take this funcion , because without it ADInterstitial iAd will not work
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidUnload");
    adShowing = false;
}
```

This code is in my GameScene class. Originally I created a new sprite kit application for testing ads(the application was portrait) and this worked fine. I ported it over onto the application I intended to publish which was horizontal and it didn't work. I set up some NSLog's to track what was being called along with a boolean adShowing which changes depending on the state of the ad. After running the application and initialising `loadInterstitialAd` I noticed that the adShowing bool would become true, a couple of seconds would pass and then 
        `"didFailWithError"`

would appear in the console indicating that the ad had failed to display which tells me that ads only work in portrait at least with my set up. Does anyone have ideas what I can do to change my code so that ads work in horizontal/landscape mode?

Kind Regards
Ryan

**EDIT**
After quite a lot of testing and dare I say it, messing about. I have noticed that the ad does work sometimes but very rarely :)

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller your game scene appears add

```
[self setInterstitialPresentationPolicy:ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual];
```

in viewDidLoad

You also need the view controller to call

```
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

So you can create a protocol in GameScene.h with a method like showInterstitialAd. Like:

```
@protocol GameSceneDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) showInterstitialAd;
@end
```

Add a delegate property to GameScene.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <GameSceneDelegate> delegate;
```

Have the view controller as it's delegate and implement something like and declare it conforms to the GameSceneDelegate protocol.

```
-(void)showInterstitialAd{
  [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
}
```

In the viewDidLoad of GameSceneController set the `gameScene.delegate = self;`

When you want to show the add in GameScene call `[self.delegate showInterstitialAd];`

Comment: thanks for the reply dude! I now get the following error on that line (before the application is run - shows in the Xcode warning section) `No visible @interface for 'GameScene' declares the selector 'setInterstitialPresentationPolicy:'`

Comment: Don't place it in game scene directly. Put it in the view controller that presents the scene. If you are using the sprite kit template from Xcode, It's called GameViewController.

Comment: I put it in the game view controller, I didn't get an error however when I run it I still get the failed message which I got originally.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I will have a look when I get back tonight and let you know the result! :)

Comment: hey man! ok Ive just got back and tried to implement your code. Can you make sure its correct and try explain it better, it doesnt seem to make much sense. Thanks! :)

Comment: I also tried your code and it still doesn't work as it stands :/

Comment: The view controller is what iAd uses to present interstitial ads. But in SpriteKit, game logic is typically placed in a SKScene. So you need to create a way of having your SKScene to talk to the ViewController that presents it. In objective C this is typically done through delegation. The protocol code should be placed in GameScene.h below your imports but above interface. The delegate property should be placed inside the GameScene.h interface. I don't know what else to say. Place an NSLog in -(void)showInterstialAd to see if it's getting called. If it's not the delegate is not setup correctly

Comment: ok I will give this a try tomorrow. Sorry if I sounded a bit rude dude I was in a bit of a rush and a little stressed :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94512/discussion-between-beyowulf-and-user2876115).